# Blank Space in Tex Macro Definition

Tags: spacing, macros

I would like to implement a queue in the following way. A macro (variable?) `\queue` holds a string that may contain dots. Substrings separated by dots are the elements of the queue. Hence, the string "a.b.c" represents a queue with 3 elements, namely "a", "b" and "c". Then I want to define a macro that receives a queue as paramenter and return the queue without the first element.

When I define it as

```
\def\firstout#1.#2{#2}
```

(without any blank spaces in the line above) or

```
\def\firstout #1.#2{#2}
```

(with one or several blank spaces between `\firstout` and `#1.#2{#2}`) it works well, that is, the following code returns "b.c" as desired:

```
\def\queue{a.b.c}
\expandafter\firstout\queue
```

But, if I define it as

```
\def\firstout#1.#2 {#2}
```

(with a blank between `\def\firstout#1.#2` and `{#2}`) or

```
\def\firstout #1.#2 {#2}
```

(with a blank after `\def\firstout` and another after `#1.#2`) then I receive the following error when I try to execute `\expandafter\firstout\queue`:

> Paragraph ended before \firstout was complete.

Why? What is the role of those blank spaces? If possible, please refer to some documentation also.

**Note**: I am using TeXMaker on MikiTeX.

Comment: You're using the wrong approach anyway: what if `\queue` expands to `X` without periods?

Comment: in your example when you say it returns `b.c` as desired, in fact it returns `b` and `.c` is left in the stream, so `b.c` is printed, but `#2` never was `b.c` and for that matter you could have defined `\def\firstout #1.{}` for the same effect. (notwithstanding `egreg`'s relevant other remark).

Comment: @egreg Yes, you are right. But I should confess that I would like to understand the blank space issue.

Comment: @jfbu Thank you, jfbu. Well, as you noted, I am new to TeX. I do not have sufficient background to understand the stream issue. I will try to learn about it. By the way, how can I force `#2` to be `b.c`?

Comment: @Franc for `#2` to be `b.c` you need something like `\def\firstout #1.#2\queueend {#2}` (recall the space of the control word is not significant) and either have `\def\queue {a.b.c.\queueend}` and `\expandafter\firstout\queue` or `\def\queue {a.b.c.}` and `\expandafter\firstout\queue\queueend`. And I have added a `.` after the last element of `\queue` (`egreg`'s remark). The control word `\queueend` may be anything not encountered in the queue elements; for example you may use `\firstout` itself to avoid a new entry in the `TeX` hash table (or a `;` perhaps). `texdoc topic`

Answer (score 5):

What are used in the macro definitions are *tokens* not characters in the input file. The space after a command name is taken as ending the command name token and is never itself tokenised. `\firstout` is *one* token. The csname token with name `firstout`. Conversely a space character after `#2` is tokenised as a character token and so `#2` becomes a delimited argument delimited by space, just as `#1` is a delimited argument delimited by `.` .

Comment: Thank you David! I got it. Do you know what is the reference for _token_ definition?

Comment: @Franc the TeXBook has the full spec for TeX's parser.